# Как переопределить кнопку в андроид приложение?

Tags: java, android

У мне в андроид приложение есть поиск, и мне нужно сделать так, чтобы вместо кнопки для переноса строки в клавиатуре, появлялась кнопка поиска.

[image: вот так выглядит клавиатура сейчас]

[image: а мне нужно так]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style `actionSearch` `android:imeOptions`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого следует добавить в к EditText свойство `android:imeOptions="actionSearch"`.
На некоторых устройствах также требуется свойство `android:inputType="text"`

И добавь в коде слушатель `TextView.OnEditorActionListener`. Например:

```
<EditText
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch" 
    android:inputType="text" />
```

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            search();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```