# Отследить кнопку в EditText

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как отследить кнопку переноса на новую строку в `EditText`?

Comment: Смотря для каких целей. Например как в ответе Андрея или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1063047/11515  - только экшн подобрать под задачу.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Как переопределить кнопку в андроид приложение?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1062953/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно отследить посредством добавления слушателя для вашего поля ввода:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher(){
  @Override
  public void onTextChanged( CharSequence txt, int start, int before, int count ) {
    if( -1 != txt.toString().indexOf("\n") ){
      //your action 
    }
  }
} );
```

есть также второй вариант, где вы отслеживаете не то что введено в поле для ввода, а нажатия на клавишу:

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {           
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    //do something here
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```